# How to mock Class.forName and class.Constructor.newInstance()

Tags: java, unit-testing

i have been trying to mock

```
clazz = Class.forName("Complete Class path") 
Object obj = clazz.Constructor().getInstance();
```

I googled it, and found links which informed how to mock the static method using powermock. I tried using those logic to mock the

`Class.forName("Complete Class path")`

and

`Object obj = clazz.Constructor().getInstance()` but have been facing errors.

```
at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor16.newInstance(Unknown Source) [junit]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) [junit] 
at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:45) [junit]
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.newInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:223) [junit]
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.newInstance(Whitebox.java:139) [junit]
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:64) [junit]
at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:203) [junit]
at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.standardInject(AnnotationEnabler.java:106) [junit]
at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:54) [junit]
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:90) [junit]
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:292) [junit]
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127) [junit]
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82) [junit]
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282) [junit]
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87) [junit]
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50) [junit]
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207) [junit]
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146) [junit]
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120) [junit]
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34) [junit]
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44) [junit]
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122) [junit]
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106) [junit]
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
```

Comment: Let me ask: why do you want to do that?

Comment: Besides: "facing" errors is not a good starting point. Give us details; otherwise you won't see any helpful feedback!

Comment: Don't.  Reorganize the code so you don't have to mock that.  Pass in a factory.

Comment: Thank you Every ONE for your time and response. :)

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry i couldn't add the exact error earlier, i have now added the exact errors i confronted.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that mocking `Class` is a good idea, you should rewrite your code to make it more testable. You should delegate your component creation to a factory, then it will be easy to mock it.

Here is how your Factory could look like:

```
public interface MyObjectFactory {
    MyObject create();
}
```

Then in the class where you need to create this object, you add the factory as field

```
public class MyClass {
    // The factory that will create my objects
    private MyObjectFactory factory;

    public void someMethod() {
        // Calls the factory to create my object 
        MyObject object = factory.create();
        ...
    }
}
```

Once done, you can use [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) to mock your `MyObjectFactory` in order to provide the instance of `MyObject` of your choice.

The test case would then be:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    @Mock
    MyObjectFactory factory;
    @InjectMocks
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {
        ...
        Mockito.when(factory.create()).thenReturn(myObject);
        // Call the method
        myClass.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, this is the **only** reasonable answer here. If somebody put an immovable object in your path; then you don't waste your time moving that thing. You walk around. And your approach is the best way of "walking" around by far!

Comment: What if you're testing the factory? :-/

Comment: @Yuval it would then be another question/subject

Comment: What if what's being tested is something that uses JUnit and wants to ensure that `@RunWith`, `@BeforeClass`, `@Before`, `@After`, `@AfterClass` (or pretty much anything that has a `Class` as a parameter) still work?

Comment: @NoelYap I'm not sure to understand your question, could you please reformulate or give an example?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, let's say I have a function that eventually calls `new JUnitCore().run(request)`. I want to ensure that any `request` that has `@RunWith(Runner.class)` actually uses `Runner.class`. Ideally, I could use a mock `Runner` instance.

Comment: @NoelYap never tested but IMHO it should work, have look to https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/test-runners

Comment: Yes, JUnit works as intended. And instead of using mocks, it uses `static` variables to spy on the inner workings. The issue I had is that our code initially didn't use `JUnitCore` and, wanting to follow TDD, I wanted to write a test ensuring that `@RunWith` would actually work. I wound up doing what JUnit itself does, using `static` variables to spy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll not succeed with mocking static `forName` method due to the fact of early `Class` loading. I don't know mock framework which could do that.

But if you are testing your own code then I'd suggest you to move `Class.forName` logic to this [strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

```
interface ClassLoadingStrategy {
    ClassLoadingStrategy DEFAULT = Class::forName;

    Class<?> forName(final String name) throws Exception;
}
```

Rewrite your code to use it where you need `Class.forName` and replace it with mock in your tests.

Comment: Mocking aint that easy. java.lang.Class is final. So I guess he still needs PowerMock to mock instances of Class.

Comment: @GhostCat I need to recheck that, but afaik mocking final classes loaded by bootstrap classloader is impossible w/o going too loow-level (i.e using javaagents)